# Tell jQuery to ignore clicks during an animation sequence

Tags: jquery, delay

I'm in the midst of writing a slide show app (click a button, and you slide through a list of images) for jQuery, but I've run into a little bug where it will respond to the `click()` request even while an animation is happening. I'm using the `animate()` function already, so that isn't staving off the additional animation requests.

Any way to program around this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check whether the animation is in progress in the `click` handler:

```
if ($(this).is(':animated')) return false;
```

Alternatively, you can use the [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) functions to only bind the handler to non-animated elements:

```
$('something:not(:animated)').live('click', function() { ... });
```